# How can I get a range in SVN "greater than and not equal to" X

Tags: svn

I'm building a script to automate some common developer tasks.

As part of this, I am given the revision in SVN that a build agent used to build artifacts (x).  I also have the revision used from the last build (y).

So to get the commit log in this range, I've been using svn log -ry:x.

The problem is this is an inclusive range, so the same change is included twice in different builds.

So I'm looking for a way I can say: "Give me the changes between the last build (which was built up through revision Y) and the current build (up through revision X)".  In other words, (y,x].

From what I can gather, this may not be possible?

Comment: Hmm, would it be sufficient to add 1 to y before passing it to the svn command line?

Comment: I tried that.  It works sometimes if that revision matches with one within the branch only. Otherwise it throws an error about no revision found.

Comment: Can you paste that *no revision found* error, @JeremyFriesner?

AFAIK, all revisions *exist* between `r0` and `HEAD` in Subversion in all branches and tags — if no actual commit was affecting that particula branch, SVN should use the first commit after that one which changed something on the branch.

Comment: @tripu SentientAI is the one who reported the error.

Comment: Oops -- thanks, @JeremyFriesner.
(The poster should have been notified automatically.)

Comment: I think @JeremyFriesner comment is the answer. I tried in one of my repos. Last branch history revisions are: 16206 <- 16195 <- 16188 <- 16186 <- 16183.  `svn log -r16184:16188` shows log for revisions 16186 and 16188. Tested with `svn, version 1.6.9 (r901367)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible, but as noted in the comments above, simply doing y+1 will *not* give the right results since that revision may be on a different branch.  So to find out what you need is the next revision after y, you need to use "svn log".

Let's assume that you are currently in your workspace (at the top) which is fully up-to-date.  I ran this example in my repository and I picked rev 5402 as the rev of my last build, this command gave me the revision range you wanted:

```
$ svn log -rHEAD:5402 | perl -ne '/^r(\d+) / and push @a, $1; END {print $a[0],":",$a[$#a-1],"\n"; } '
5531:5423
```

So, what I am doing is picking out the sequence of revision numbers going back to rev 5402, then I pick out the first rev (the HEAD I am looking at), and the *next to last* rev (the last rev would be 5402).  As you can see, this skipped over the 20 intervening changes on other branches.

Note that the code above does not deal with the case where there have been no changes (that is when x == y), but I presume your build scripts wouldn't get this far in that case.